# ESP/ASR fault and no power on my Peugeot Expert 2015 2.0 Diesel

Tags: oil, clutch, power, peugeot, power-loss

My car accelerated very much (kind of like pressing the clutch while accelerating) with a ton of white smoke coming from the exhaust, then it lost power, and the triangle and ESP lights showed on the dashboard. Now I have an ESP/ASR fault, and I don't have power in the car.

Is this caused by some sensor not functioning properly? Could it be an over filled coolant tank (I over filled the coolant earlier that day)? I also poured some extra oil.  Could too much oil, cause this issue? I see some oil leaking underneath,though nothing on the ground. I felt a little burn in the cabin while driving prior to the issue.

I also saw, when changing discs and pads two months ago, a cut cable hanging around my right wheel. Is this some sensor cable? It seems to drive without problem so far. The clutch was also changed about 2 months ago, so I have feeling that the cable was damaged by the garage. Anyone have some idea what is causing this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If you overfilled the oil - then the excess can be forced into the induction system and, as it is diesel, this provides extra "fuel" for the engine causing it to over-rev. You need to read the codes and you may have a chance of sorting it.

There are videos of this happening to diesel engines on **otube, and it can be terminal ie the engine damages itself - rod goes through the block etc.

Comment: thanks . what are the signs if rod goes through? engine seems working fine. when i press accelerator no power.i didn't have any fumes when  opened oil cap. No signs of oil in the coolant and no sign of oil in the water. fuel pump? inter-cooler pipe/hose loose? air flow blocked? i am trying to search , but could be anything. and i have no engine warning light on dashboard, just triangle and esp . thanks again

Comment: the signs of a rod going through the block are noise, broken bits, massive oil leak, engine won't run etc